# CS50 finance: RuntimeError: cannot start a transaction within a transaction

Tags: python, sql, flask, cs50

So, I'm trying to do the CS50 finance task, for those who don't know it, its a flask app within you can quote for the stock market and buy them, anyway I'm trying set a route that allows the user to buy a quote stock market, here is the code where the problem appears:

```py
        # Adding the values into the purchases table
        try:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO purchases(user_id, company_symbol, name, shares, price, total_price, transaction_time) VALUES (:user_id, :symbol, :name, :shares, :price, :total_price, :transaction_time)",
                    user_id=user_id, symbol=quote["symbol"], name=quote["name"], shares=shares, price=quote["price"], total_price=total_price, transaction_time=transaction_time)
        except:
            value = db.execute("SELECT shares, price, total_price FROM purchases WHERE user_id = :user_id", user_id=user_id)
            for item in value:
                item["shares"] = item["shares"] + shares
                item["total_price"] = item["total_price"] + total_price
                db.execute("UPDATE purchases SET shares = :shares, price = :price, total_price = :total_price WHERE user_id = :user_id",
                            shares=item["shares"], price=quote["price"], total_price=item["total_price"], user_id=user_id)

    return render_template("bought.html")
```

in the `try` section I'm trying to `INSERT` the values into the table purchases and that works, the problem is in the `expect` section, this part is called when the user already buys the same quote, its job is to `UPDATE` the values in the table purchases but when it run it run an error.

the error:

```
RuntimeError: cannot start a transaction within a transaction
```

HERE IS THE FULL ROUTE:

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("buy.html")
    else:
        # Getting the form values
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol")
        shares = float(request.form.get("shares"))
        quote = lookup(symbol)

        # Checking for iput errors
        if not symbol:
            return apology("MISSING SYMBOL")
        elif not shares:
            return apology("MISSING SHARES")
        elif quote == None:
            return apology("INVALID SYMBOL")

        # Cheking if affordable
        user_id = session["user_id"]
        user_wallet = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :user_id", user_id=user_id)
        total_price = quote["price"] * shares

        for wallet in user_wallet:
            if total_price > wallet['cash']:
                return apology("CAN'T AFFORD")

        # Getting the current time
        transaction_time = datetime.datetime.now()

        # Creating the purchases table if not exist
        db.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS purchases (user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, company_symbol TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, shares NUMERIC NOT NULL, price NUMERIC NOT NULL, total_price NUMERIC NOT NULL,transaction_time datetime NOT NULL,FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users(id))")

        # Adding the values into the purchases table
        try:
            db.execute("INSERT INTO purchases(user_id, company_symbol, name, shares, price, total_price, transaction_time) VALUES (:user_id, :symbol, :name, :shares, :price, :total_price, :transaction_time)",
                    user_id=user_id, symbol=quote["symbol"], name=quote["name"], shares=shares, price=quote["price"], total_price=total_price, transaction_time=transaction_time)
        except:
            value = db.execute("SELECT shares, price, total_price FROM purchases WHERE user_id = :user_id", user_id=user_id)
            for item in value:
                item["shares"] = item["shares"] + shares
                item["total_price"] = item["total_price"] + total_price
                db.execute("UPDATE purchases SET shares = :shares, price = :price, total_price = :total_price WHERE user_id = :user_id",
                            shares=item["shares"], price=quote["price"], total_price=item["total_price"], user_id=user_id)

    return render_template("bought.html")
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your quotation marks are all over the place. Try to correct them so that the piece that is executed in db is just a single string. Maybe use `'`.

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: What is the primary key on purchases table? What exception is being thrown? Be aware that the UPDATE query will update _all_ records in purchases table for user_id.

Comment: the purchases table does not have a primary key the value user_id is the value of id that is taken from another table called users, I'm sorry if I couldn't explain it very well I'm just a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This "*this part is called when the user already buys the same quote*" is at the heart of the problem. If `purchases` does not have a primary key, the system *cannot know* that the user already bought the same quote. If the INSERT failed on a UNIQUENESS constraint, this code would work fine. It cannot be failing on uniqueness since purchases does not have a PK, so why is the insert failing?

Best guess:

- The table is not created because it already exists
- The insert is failing because of some schema problem, eg invalid column name

Troubleshooting:

- change `except:` to `except Exception as e:`
- add `print(e)` as the first line in the except block
- when the error occurs, back up through the flask log to see what exception is being thrown
- correct the problem as necessary

Design:
If the purchases table is meant to keep track of a user's holdings by symbol, the table needs a primary key on user_id,symbol. The UPDATE needs to be modified to accommodate that (id WHERE user_id = sth AND symbol = sth).

I cannot explain the runtime error technically. It is a quirk of the interface that can be corrected by correcting the underlying problem.